# Inputting a function into an imported module

Tags: python, function, module

I am attempting to create a game menu that I can then use in games to skip having to make a new menu each time. However, currently it just preforms the gameMain() function instead of doing the gameMenu() first, and then trying to select the game with "g" or "G" does nothing but end the program.

What I'm asking is if it's possible to have a variable in a module that's a function in the code that's importing it.

Here is the code for the menu, which is called textbasedadventures.py:

```
def gameMenu(game,your_choice="Please Enter how you'd like the game described"):
    menu_options = ""
    while not(menu_options == "G" or menu_options == "g":
        title()
        print()
        print("\t\t",your_choice,"\n\n")
        print('G start game')
        menu_options = input("\t\tChoice: ")
        if menu_options == "G" or menu_options == "g":
            game

            input(pause)
```

and this is the code for the game:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("\MyOwnProjects")
import textbasedadventures as t
def veryStart():
    answer = ""
    while not(answer == "1" or answer == "2" or answer == "3"):
        print("\tYou are awoken by the blaring of your alarm clock.How did you sleep last night?")
        print("\n\t1 Very well\n\n\t2 Well\n\n\t3 Not good\n\n\t4 atrociously")
        answer = input("You slept ")
        if answer == "1":
            print("one option")
        elif answer == "2":
            print("\t")
        elif answer == "3":
            pass
        elif answer == "4":
            print("another option")
        else:
            print("\t",answer,"is not a valid entry, please try again")


def gameMain():

    veryStart()


t.gameMenu(gameMain(),"please work")
```

If anyone can tell me how to do this, or if this is even possible, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: You're almost there -- please (1) Research how to make and use modules.  If this doesn't solve your problem ... (2) Give us that *minimal* example.  What you posted includes a lot of textual fluff that doesn't drive the problem.  (3) Clarify your terms: *how* is `t` a "nickname" for your file.  Include *all* the code we need, not a description in colloquial terms.

Comment: I did my best to edit it, I hope I did it right? I'm new here and I'm just doing my best. And I have been researching this problem for at least 3 days no to no success.

Comment: Not quite: your posted code doesn't run due to syntax errors.  Much better than the original, though ...

Comment: *Exactly* how did you define `textbasedadventures`?  Also, what have you found on line about linking modules?  This looks to me like something that's covered with basic tutorials on the topic, not to mention quite a few Stack Overflow questions already here.

Comment: Please do not insult me, I looked at all the basic tutorials I could find and not one of them covered having a variable in a module that is a function in the code that is importing that module. If I missed that, please link it to me, and I'll delete this apparently terrible question. If not, please do not insult me, I'm just a newbie and I don't want any harm to anyone.

Comment: Not intended as an insult ... trying to determine the missing issue, which I think you just supplied: you're having trouble with passing your game function as a variable to a module function.

Comment: *How* did you call that first chunk of code `textbasedadventures`?  Is the file name `textbasedadventures.py`?  There are a lot of details to link code to another file ... the first few times you do it ...

Comment: Oh, gosh I'm sorry! I've just never ever asked a form for help like this, and I was kind of scared I'd be kicked out for asking a dumb question or something, so I got really stressed. I'll update the question to hopefully be more clear. Sorry again.

Comment: This is how we all learn.  Welcome to the community.  I'm now working on your code ... still a couple of minor problems, but ... close enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your remaining problem is getting used to when you're *calling* a function, and when you're referring to the *function as an object*.

Since you didn't get any errors when you imported your `textbasedadventures` (which I shortened to `tba` to avoid typos), I assume that you've handled that properly: the file is named `textbasedadventures.py` and is in the local directory.

I had to remove the `input(pause)` line, since you didn't define `pause`, and it's there for a different shell from the one I'm using.  I also had to remove `title()`, since that's no longer in your code.

When you pass the main program's main-game function, you have to pass it as a *function object*.  You did this:

```
t.gameMenu(gameMain(),"please work")
```

This *calls* gameMain (because of the parentheses), grabs the return value, and passes *that* to `t.gameMenu`.  Since there *isn't* any such return value, your remote menu routien receives only the value `None`.

Simply remove the parentheses:

```
t.gameMenu(gameMain,"please work")
```

This takes the entire `gameMain` function (well, a reference to it) and passes that to your remote function, where ...

Instead of calling the passed-in `game` module, you simply listed its value.  Python thinks, "okay, cool, I have to evaluate this expression.  Gee, a reference to an object -- that's easy.  The value is simply the reference itself.  I'm not even supposed to *do* anything with it.  Done."

Simply putting a value on a line is legal Python, but boring: the value is displayed if you're in an interactive shell, but is otherwise ignored.  Therefore, you never got any response from that line.

Instead, *now* you call it: this is where you put the parentheses you took off the other end of the call:

```
game()
```

I made those changes, and here's the result:

```
enter G to start game
        Choice: g
    You are awoken by the blaring of your alarm clock.How did you sleep last night?

    1 Very well

    2 Well

    3 Not good

    4 atrociously
You slept
```